# not able to serve django-admin files aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-admin

I have a django(1.7) project on aws with apache2 server. All the other static files are loading except the admin site files.

I have given the path of static url and also run the command `manage.py collectstatic`.

`collectedstatic` folder has also been created but admin files are still not being served.

Answer (score -1):

I might suggest using `django-admin.py collectstatic`, or doing it manually- go to your static folder `~/django/contrib/admin/static`, and copy/paste its contents to the project static directory.